# Evaluating $1+\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{3+\cdots}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continued-fractions

I was messing around on desmos and accidentally mistyped and wrote "$1+1/(2-1/3+)$" instead of "$1+(1/2)-(1/3)+$".  Anyways, I thought I might continue that trend and try to see what that infinite series
$$1+\frac{1}{2-\dfrac{1}{3+\dfrac{1}{4-\dfrac{1}{5+\dfrac{1}{6-\dfrac{1}{7+\cdots}}}}}}$$ 
would look like. I found that this series of fractions converged rapidly on a value that is something like $1.59049113525$ after 10 iterations.

Could someone tell me what this fraction is and what it eventually approaches?

Comment: Congratulations! You have (re)discovered [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction). They're pretty neat.

Comment: Hmm... Wikipedia's list of mathematical constants does not contain any number that starts with $1.59$. Now I really want to know.

Comment: Simple continued fractions with partial quotients in arithmetic progression can be expressed in terms of Bessel functions, by a theorem of Lehmer. The minus signs mean that your continued fraction is not a simple continued fraction, but there may be a transformation to make it one.

Comment: Yeah I knew what continued fractions were before this, I just have never seen this particular one. That is why I was curious. By the way thank you to whomever made those fractions look good, I am grateful.

Comment: The inverse symbolic calculator [doesn't know this value](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=1.59049113525&lookup_type=simple).